# Use of Float/Decimal in Calculating Growth Rate in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I have an events table with userid, occured_at, event_type columns.**
I am trying to calculate the week-on-week growth rate in the number of users with the following query.
I am confused if I should use Float or Decimal. Both give me the same result. But inherently what is the difference between the two and which should be used when.

Kindly help.

```
with temp1 AS
(select date_trunc('week', occurred_at) as week, count(distinct(user_id)) as number_of_users
from tutorial.yammer_events 
where event_type = 'engagement'
group by week)
select week, number_of_users,
 ((number_of_users :: float - lag(number_of_users) over (ORDER by week)::float)/
 lag(number_of_users) over (ORDER by week)::float)*100 as growth_rate
from temp1
order by week;
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` describes one of the floating-point types `double` or `real`. The precision is variable (`real` up to 6 digits, `double` up to 15 digits) but the storage size fix.
While `numeric` and `decimal` ()arbitrary precision types have user-specified precision, so it's storage size is variable.

Arbitrary precision types can perform exact calculations but are slower than the floating point types on arithmetic calculations.

See more details here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: So what do I use in my query here?

Comment: I think you need neither a fix precision nor an exact calculation, so I think going for float (double/real) is a good choice.

Comment: so the above query is correct as is, right?

Comment: Did't tested it but this part `((number_of_users :: float - lag(number_of_users) over (ORDER by week)::float)/
 lag(number_of_users) over (ORDER by week)::float)*100 as growth_rate` seems correct besides that it would work also without casting the divisor to float...

Comment: Is the answer acceptable or does it need more clarification @Ashima?